# How to catch groups occurring more than once using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

Given this example input string.

```
String str = 
   "[{\"ID\":\"A001\",\"Name\":\"Captain America\",\"State\":\"Brooklyn\"},
     {\"ID\":\"A002\",\"Name\":\"Iron Man\",\"State\":\"New York\"}]"
```

I'm trying to use a regex to extract all the values associated with key "Name".

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\"name\":(\".*\").*");  
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);  
if(m.find()){
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
   System.out.println(m.group(2));            
}
```

I'm trying to achieve the following output:

```
Captain America
Iron Man
```

But the code above produces this instead:

```
"Iron Man","state":"New York"
```

Would also appreciate recommendations for techniques for doing something similar working with same String data directly on a Java JSONObject instead.

Comment: Don't parse JSON with regex. Just don't.

Comment: GSON is a good JSON parser.

Comment: Is this not possible in string?

Comment: I am dealing with HTTPResponse here. In this case I have the JSON as follows

{"headers":{}
  ,"body": "[{\"ID\":\"A001\",\"Name\":\"Captain America\",\"State\":\"Brooklyn\"},{\"ID\":\"A002\",\"Name\":\"Iron Man\",\"State\":\"New York\"}]"
  ,"status":200}

How will I do the needy here

Comment: As per my understanding here value of body is String right?

Comment: You do know that Regex is case-sensitive, right? The string shows "Name" but regex is matching on "name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "[{\"ID\":\"A001\",\"Name\":\"Captain America\",\"State\":\"Brooklyn\"},{\"ID\":\"A002\",\"Name\":\"Iron Man\",\"State\":\"New York\"}]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\"Name\":\")(.*?)(?=\",\"State\")");  
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
Captain America
Iron Man
```

A better option would be to use a `JSON` Parser...

Comment: How to do it using JSON parser ? I tried doing

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str) 

is this wrong?

Comment: You would need to read the documentation for whatever library you are using...

Comment: the regex provided still returns only one value

Comment: Lets say I have the JSON Object as you said. 
This is in the format 
{"headers":{} ,"body": "[{\"ID\":\"A001\",\"Name\":\"Captain America\",\"State\":\"Brooklyn\"},{\"ID\":\"A002\",\"Name\":\"Iron Man\",\"State\":\"New York\"}]" ,"status":200} 
How will get name here?

Comment: @Srikanth no it returns all the values for `name`, did you try to run it. I just ran it in eclipse and it prints exactly what i said `Captain America` and `Iron Man`...copy my code exactly and run it...

Comment: @Srikanth it will print all `Name` attributes even if there are 100 or 200 or 1000 etc...